# How to pass traffic from static ip on my router through Ubuntu firewall to LAN ip

Tags: firewall

I have a router that has 5 static ip addresses set on it. These external static IP's are mapped to internal IP's on our LAN. We currently have no firewall or proxy set up, so I cannot monitor user bandwidth usage or block content.

I have set up an Ubuntu firewall with 2 network cards and Squid proxy and am able to connect to the internet via the firewall from a workstation within the LAN.

I am also familiar with port forwarding through the Ubuntu firewall, however, how can I map an external IP address to an address on the internal IP ?  The router has a static IP address on the LAN (192.168.0.2), my Ubuntu Firewall has a static IP address of 192.168.0.3 on the "WAN" network card and an address of 10.10.10.1 on the "LAN" network card. My clients on the LAN are within the address range of 10.10.10.1 - 10.10.10.255.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: You initially said that "These external static IP's are mapped to internal IP's on our LAN." and then ask the question: "how can I map an external IP address to an address on the internal IP". Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Do  your router supports NAT ?

Comment: Do you have taken static ip  from ISP ?

Comment: Sorry, yes, my current setup excludes the Ubuntu Firewall so my LAN workstations are connected directly to the router, so they are all on the same network range ie 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.255. I am wanting to use Ubuntu as a firewall and proxy but still require the static IP to be passed through to workstations on the LAN.

Comment: Yes, the static IP is from the ISP and the router does support NAT.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you set up your squid proxy machine to have multiple IP addresses on the WAN facing side - one corresponding to each of your 5 client machines on the LAN (say 192.168.0.3, 192.168.0.4, 192.168.0.5, 192.168.0.6 and 192.168.0.7).

You then set up a squid ACL and tcp_outgoing_address rule as described [here](http://linuxaria.com/pills/setup-squid-to-use-multiple-outgoing-ip-addresses?lang=en) to map your internal client LAN addreses to one of the WAN facing IP addresses on squid, e.g. 10.10.10.1 maps to 192.168.0.3, 10.10.10.2 maps 192.168.0.4 etc).

Finally you set up your router to NAT your first external IP to 192.168.0.3, your second one to 192.168.0.4, and so on.